# Augmented Dickey Fuller Test interpretation

Tags: time-series

I'm running the augmented Dickey-Fuller-Test for two different Time Series and I have a question about the results in column "Variable". Why is there sometimes Y(-1) and D(Y(-1)) and sometimes only Y(-1)? And can I use the same detrending method for both time series?

[image]

and

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The difference follows the different lag length. In the first case the lag length is 1 and in the second the lag length is 0. The program (Eviews?) calculated the lag length automatically based on AIC. You can also determine it manually.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and yes it's Eviews. So in the  second picture the time series only follows a trend while in the first picture the time series follows and trend and also depends on the value of the last period?

Comment: The test-statistic of a adf-test follows y(t)-y(t-1)=D(Y(t))=c+a*y(t-1)+b*D(Y(t-1))+d*trend. If you have a lag then you input D(Y(t-1)) in your equation. C is the intercept. But you have no trend in your tests.

Comment: What do you mean with "I have no trend"? Do you mean "no trend" regarding D(Y(t-1)) because both time series definitely have a unit root (and therefore a stochastic trend) but only based on Y(-1) (or is this statement totally wrong?)

Comment: In your test statistic, you have no deterministic trend. But you a right, you have a unit root (stochatsic trend) in both equations.

Comment: Thank you again. Maybe the last question: Which detrending method is the best for a time series with a stochastic trend?

Comment: Mostly, I read: ln(Yt-Yt-1). I think Yt/Yt-1-1 works good as well, but the differences Yt-Yt-1 should be use with caution.

Comment: Well the time series is already logarithmized so it would be Y_t-Y_t-1 but I'm still struggling with the results I get. Especially when I use another detrending method like the Hodrick-Prescott-Filter I get counter-intuitive results.

Comment: If you already use ln then you should use the difference. I do not think that a Hodrick-Prescott Filter solve the unit root problem. Do you have literature that show that?

Comment: The Hodrick-Prescott-Filter is one of many different detrending methods. See for example http://apps.eui.eu/Personal/Canova/Articles/debucy.pdf (38 pages) or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodrick%E2%80%93Prescott_filter.
it is often used to separate cyclical fluctuations from trend. And the cyclical fluctuations don't have a unit root.